# GDB wont recognize new files/lines

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, qemu, xv6

i am trying to debug xv6, using qemu emulator, with gdb kernel.

How ever, gdb wont recognize any additions i do to the files. for example, it wont recognize new files, or even new lines in a existing file, for example:

in file x86.h i have added anouther function, this is the code (i have added cas):

```
static inline void
lcr3(uint val)
{
  asm volatile("movl %0,%%cr3" : : "r" (val));
}

static inline uint
cas(volatile int *addr,int expected, int newval)
{
  uint flags;
  uint zf;
  asm volatile("movl %0,%%eax;lock;cmpxchg %2,%3;jne afterChange;movl %%eax,%0;afterChange:;pushfl; popl %1":"+m"(*addr),"=r"(flags):"r"(expected),"r"(newval):"%eax");
  zf = (flags >> 6) & 1;
  return zf;
}
```

gdb will recognize lcr3, but wont recognize cas, however, when i actually search the file, i can find the lines:

```
(gdb) list lcr3
138   return val;
139 }
140 
141 static inline void
142 lcr3(uint val)
143 {
144   asm volatile("movl %0,%%cr3" : : "r" (val));
145 }
146 
147 static inline uint
(gdb) list
148 cas(volatile int *addr,int expected, int newval)
149 {
150   uint flags;
151   uint zf;
152   asm volatile("movl %0,%%eax;lock;cmpxchg %2,%3;jne afterChange;movl %%eax,%0;afterChange:;pushfl; popl %1":"+m"(*addr),"=r"(flags):"r"(expected),"r"(newval):"%eax");
153   //zf = (flags >> 6) & 1;
154   zf = flags;
155   return zf;
156 }
157
```

i am using this makefile (the basic xv6 makefile):
https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/Makefile

Would be glad for any assistance. thank you.

Comment: Presumably, it's still fixated on old ones.

Comment: how do i fix that? i have tried looking for modified gdb files, or even reinstalling gdb

Comment: `make clean`. Recompile.

Comment: Thought it was some thing else, ofcourse i have tried to recompile, did make clean more then once, more then that, i have created a new copy, updated the modified files, and compiled (fresh). did not work

Comment: What is the output of `nm kernel | grep cas` ?

Comment: Do you have any code that calls `cas`? If you don't call a static inline function anywhere, its code won't be put into the object file (unless you compile with the `-fkeep-inline-functions` option). http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: Yes, i had code calling it, infact i had a whole target which was compiling, working and using cas, but GDB did not recognize the new target (unless i moved "step by step" into the code).  However, the problem solved itself, for no apparant reason, i did nothing different :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gdb wont recognize any additions i do to the files.
>   i have created a new copy, updated the modified files, and compiled (fresh). did not work

This very likely means that you are debugging an old copy of the file you *think* you are debugging.

Do this:

1. `ls -il xv6` to observe its (recent) timestamp. It should be recent because you've done `make clean` and rebuilt it.
2. now `rm -f xv6; ls -l xv6` to verify that the file is gone.
3. now try to debug it again, and observe that you still can (which proves my guess).
4. figure out what copy you are *actually* debugging, and update *it*.
5. Profit.

**Update:**

> I am updating the right files, as i mentioned in the initial post, when i actually look into the files content using gdb i can see the modifications.

You are (apparently) talking about source files. GDB *doesn't care* about source files, and *doesn't use* them (except when you ask GDB to `list` them). GDB only cares about the *compiled* binary, and *that* is the file you are somehow neglecting to update.

Comment: I am updating the right files, as i mentioned in the initial post, when i actually look into the files content using gdb i can see the modifications. it just wont recognize any new symbols, or new files.  I have updated my repository with the changes, removed any trace of xv6 from the system, cloned it back, all the files with the additiong, in all the branches. and still, it wont recognize the new functions.

Comment: thank you, but i did not neglect to update any binary, i have erased the binary and compiled it again more then once.  However, the problem solved it self, for no apparant reason, and without me doing any thing different, 1 "make clean qemu-gdb" did not work properly, and the one right after did.

Comment: @OrDinari I believe you have the wrong attitude here If you've done everything correctly, you wouldn't have a problem. You *do* have a problem, therefore you have *not* done everything correctly. I suggested one way you could have figured out what your mistake was. Instead of doing that confirmation, you performed a series of unknown steps, and the problem cured itself, without you getting any closer to understanding it. Enjoy your newly working situation while it lasts. Next time the problem returns (as such problems tend to), try methodical approach,